# Is there a way to add a Script to an HTML file that will only affect the homepage of the site?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a situation where I can only edit this overarching html file that affects all other pages on the site. It's not an ideal situation and this isn't what I usually do, so it's a bit difficult to navigate.

What I'd like to do is add a few `<script>` tags within the `<head>` tag and have the scripts only affect the .com homepage. Is it possible to accomplish that with just the use of the `<script>` tags and maybe some extra html?

Comment: Since you have an unusual arrangement, we're going to need more information, especially a minimal example. Also, you say "with **just** the use of the <script> tags and maybe some extra html". You'll likely need to add additional javascript beyond what you already want to add.

Comment: The script can test `location.href` to see if it's running on the home page. If it's not, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: How do you have an "overarching html file"? Are you using server-side includes to insert this file into all the other files?

Comment: @Barmar It's basically an old theme file on the Shopify platform. I didn't create it, but I have to edit it to include the functionality of a script. Don't want the script to work anywhere but a particular page (homepage in this case).

Comment: @Barmar Btw, if it's not too much trouble, could you provide an example of how I would use `location.href` to activate the script?

Comment: See the answer that Simon posted, it's essentially what I was suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like the following perhaps...

Add this script to your index page.

```
<script>
    if(location.pathname == '/'){
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
            var yourScript = document.createElement('script');
            yourScript.src = '[LOCATION TO YOUR SCRIPT HERE]';    
            document.head.appendChild(yourScript);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Another user commented above about the use of `location.href`. Would you know between the two which would be the simpler solution?

Comment: This is simpler, since location.href contains the full URL.

Comment: I see, so in this example, I would create a separate .js file with the script, add it to my directory (in my case, to my Shopify assets) then input the name of my file.js where it says [LOCATION TO YOUR SCRIPT HERE]?

Comment: Just add my snippet above you your HTML page and yes, replace the placeholder I left for you with the location of the new javascript file that you want to add.

Comment: @SimonK I'm testing out the creation of a button to see if it works and it hasn't been working so far. I'm guessing because I'm not inputting the location correctly. I created the script as test.js and it sits in the assets folder of my shopify theme. I wonder if there's a specific way to refer to its location.

Comment: Ok, I've figured out the way to do it for shopify.